# WordPress post query

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to show posts with the tag "medical" if they are a child of page 843, and so far, I have everything mostly working. I need to get some HTML within this if statement so that I can enclose it all in a div, and also to set an opening and closing ul for the list.

Can someone please help me get over this last hump?  I'm just not sure where to add the HTML.

```
<?php
if (843 == $post->post_parent) {
global $post;
$myposts = get_posts('numberposts=10&tag=medical&order=DESC');
foreach($myposts as $post) :
?>
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a to enclose all the posts in a div:

```
<?php
global $post;
if (843 == $post->post_parent) {
    $myposts = get_posts('numberposts=10&tag=medical&order=DESC');
    echo '<div><ul>';
    foreach ($myposts as $post): ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach;
    echo '</ul></div>';
} ?>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, David.  Is it possible to get that last div inside the if statement?  Is it best to then echo it?

Comment: @Alex was right. I think you need the `global $post before the if. Yea, you just echo the div and ul tags around the foreach loop but inside the if block.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just do something like the following?

```
<div id="wrap">
<ul>
<?php
if (843 == $post->post_parent) {
global $post;
$myposts = get_posts('numberposts=10&tag=medical&order=DESC');
foreach($myposts as $post) :
?>
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach;
}
?>
</ul>
</div> <!-- #wrap !-->
```

Comment: I should have specified that I need to have the div and UL inside the if statement, because I don't want anything to appear if the page does not meet the criteria.

Answer (score 1):

First, you call the global $post variable before the if statement, and re-write the condition this way :

```
global $post
if ($post->post_parent = 843)
```

Also, you cannot use the functions the_permalink() and the_title() outside the loop, you have to use, instead, the functions get_the_permalink(ID) and get_the_title(ID) this way (and also, $post is ambiguous, you should use another variable name):

```
<div><ul>
<?php foreach($myposts as $mypost) : ?>
<li><a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($mypost->ID); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($mypost->ID); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach;
}?>
</ul></div>
```